# Getting rid of "Having trouble accessing your Google Account with an application or device?"

Tags: gmail, multi-factor-auth

I'm someone who has been using 2 step verification for a year now.

Recently, I keep getting the following email from `no-reply@accounts.google.com`:

> Hi Manish,
>
> Did you recently get an error about your password being wrong when you
>   tried to check your Gmail or access your Google Calendar or Contacts
>   for blahblahblah@gmail.com?
>
> Since you added 2-Step Verification to your account for additional
>   security, accessing your Google Account requires both your password
>   and a verification code provided by Google. However, certain apps
>   can’t be configured to use verification codes. Here are some examples:
>
> - Mail, Calendar, Contacts app on iPhone, iPad
> - Microsoft Outlook
>
> Don’t worry — you can still access your account from these apps and
>   continue to use 2-Step Verification. All you have to do is configure
>   that app with a special type of password called an “app-specific
>   password”. Google will generate it for you, you’ll only have to enter
>   it once, and you won’t need to remember it.
>
> To get your app-specific password, visit: 
>   https://support.google.com/accounts/troubleshooter/3141849.
>
> Sincerely, The Google Accounts team    This email can't receive replies.
>   For more information, visit the [Google Accounts Help Center.](https://support.google.com/accounts/troubleshooter/3141849)

I get this email every day. I know what application passwords are, and for the life of me I can't think of any app that I use that would trigger this — I don't recall logging in to my GMail from any persistent device/app in the recent past.

Is there a way to stop this email? Or to trace what is triggering it?